# How to limit data in a mobile API using EF and WebAPI/JSON

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-5

I am writing a PhoneGap/Web/JS mobile application that uses the WebAPI and Entity Framework in the backend.

I have a class called Thing which references the User table 4 times (ChangedByUserId, CreatedByUserId etc.  The User table is really large (30 user-related fields)

I want to pass as little data over each call as possible, but I need the User's Name for each of these UserID foreign keys. (this is the only information from the user record I need).

When I use the object graph in EF it returns the FULL user record for each foreign key, so a single Thing object becomes massively bloated. I don't want to make multiple calls to get the Thing POCO object and then the User's name by UserID.

What I really want to do is a sort of flattened DTO object which is just the Thing class below but with a string for each user name, e.g. CreatedByUserName, ChangedByUserName etc. Then I would return this DTO as my hydrated POCO object and the data would be small.

So my question is: How do I do this using Entity Framework? (limit related record's return data?)

```
public partial class Thing
{
    public int ThingId { get; set; }
    public int FromUserId { get; set; }
    public int ToUserId { get; set; }
    public string ThingText { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public int ChangedByUserId { get; set; }
    public int CreatedByUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User FromUser { get; set; }
    public virtual User ToUser { get; set; }
    public virtual User CreatedByUser { get; set; }
    public virtual User ChangedByUser { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, you need to flatten Thing

```
public class FlatThing
{
    public int ThingId { get; set; }
    public int FromUserId { get; set; }
    public int ToUserId { get; set; }
    public string ThingText { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public int ChangedByUserId { get; set; }
    public int CreatedByUserId { get; set; }

    public string FromUserName { get; set; }
    public string ToUserName{ get; set; }
 }

 // assume you have your things

var flatThings = new List<FlatThings>;
foreach (Thing t in things)
    flatThings.Add(new FlatThing{ ThingId = t.ThingId, FromUserId = t.FromUserId,
                                  FromUserName = t.FromUser.Name .....});

return flatThings;
```

Comment: Thanks, I have now switched to Breeze JS for my data layer (it does OData Expands)